# How to Fetch the names of the files that has been generated inside the migration folder? I just want the list of files inside migration folder

Tags: file, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, database-migration

I want to fetch the list of files that has been generated inside the migration folder so I tried using getassembly() method but did'nt work how to fetch it? are there any ways?

I tried it using the GetAssembly() methods but did not work

Comment: What migration? Please, post the code you have tried so far and explain why it didn't work? It does not compile? It does not produce the desired output?